# How can I customize the color of a Checkbox in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) in my project, and I have a `Checkbox` within a `div` with a black background. But it doesn't look good because the `Checkbox` is black too. How can I change the color of the `Checkbox` from black to another color?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use the `iconStyle`, but since the checkbox icon is an SVG image, you need to set the color using `fill` instead of `color`:

https://jsfiddle.net/27Lmaz48/1/

```
<Checkbox label='My checkbox' 
  labelStyle={{color: 'white'}}
  iconStyle={{fill: 'white'}}
/>
```

Comment: Can you do a hex color instead of a named color?

Comment: If there is one thing I can blame material-ui for is their lack of examples on their website .. It is full of working examples, but they never ever show the original code ..

Comment: which version of material-ui using ?

Comment: I think this answer is outdated for Material UI 4.11.3

Answer (score 51):

This is how you do it:

```
 <FormControlLabel  
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={cryon}
                    onChange={this.handleChange('cryon')}
                    style ={{
                      color: "#00e676",
                    }}
                    value="cryon"
                  />
                }
                label={<Typography variant="h6" style={{ color: '#2979ff' }}>Work</Typography>}
              />
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution since it's simple to apply and effects both checked and unchecked colors. Works with material-ui 4.8.0

Comment: Was trying to set the color in the Checkbox `sx` prop but it doesn't work. I have to use the `style` prop. (v5.13.1)

Answer (score 25):

It's an old question, but for those who are using material 1.2.

The iconStyle is not working for me.

However, I achieved this by overwriting the existing theme and wrap the 'Checkbox' component to a new one.

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';



const checkBoxStyles = theme => ({
    root: {
      '&$checked': {
        color: '#3D70B2',
      },
    },
    checked: {},
   })

const CustomCheckbox = withStyles(checkBoxStyles)(Checkbox);
```

Now you can use the "CustomCheckbox" component in render function.

And when it's checked , the color should be the one you assigned.

[image: example]

Answer (score 11):

In **MUI v5**, There are 2 preferable ways to change the `Checkbox` color:

### [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) prop

This is useful for one-off style, quickly to set up but only apply to a specific `Checkbox`:

```
import Checkbox, { checkboxClasses } from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
```

```
<Checkbox
  {...props}
  sx={{
    [`&, &.${checkboxClasses.checked}`]: {
      color: 'magenta',
    },
  }}
/>
```

### `color` prop

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264263/9449426) answer for more detail. Basically the `color` prop of some components (e.g. `Button`, `Checkbox`, `Radio`,...) must be one of the colors from the [`Palette`](https://mui.com/system/palette/#main-content) object, which can be extended to your liking:

```
import { pink, yellow } from "@mui/material/colors";
import Checkbox, { checkboxClasses } from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const { palette } = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    pinky: palette.augmentColor({ color: pink }),
    summer: palette.augmentColor({ color: yellow })
  }
});
```

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  {/* pre-defined color */}
  <Checkbox />
  <Checkbox color="secondary" />
  <Checkbox color="success" />
  <Checkbox color="default" />
  {/* custom color */}
  <Checkbox color="pinky" />
  <Checkbox color="summer" />
  <Checkbox
</ThemeProvider>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related Answer

- [How to add custom MUI palette colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264263/9449426)

Comment: this should be the answer in 2023. this code is piece of chocolate .

Comment: sx prop solution is easy and this works in 2024. Very useful. I tried many thing but this this worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [material ui theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/).

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCheckbox: {
      colorSecondary: {
        color: '#custom color',
        '&$checked': {
          color: '#custom color',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[got it from here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13895#issuecomment-447648634)

Comment: This is great! I added it for `colorPrimary` for my use case.

Answer (score 6):

For me it is solve by adding root and checked classed

```
const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    "&$checked": {
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)"
    }
  },
  checked: {}
})
```

and passing it inside classes of checkbox

```
<Checkbox
          checked={checked}
          classes={{
            root: classes.root,
            checked: classes.checked
          }}
          onChange={handleCheckBox}
        />
```

hope this will help others

Answer (score 5):

Could be two approaches.

1. "local"

CheckBox has props `labelStyle` and `iconStyle`.
I suppose you can start with adjusting them:

```
<Checkbox
  label="Custom icon"
  labelStyle={{color: 'white'}}
  iconStyle={{color: 'white'}}
/>
```

I'm not sure if it's enough so may be you need to play with other "Style" [props of Checkbox](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox). Checkout everything that has "style" in name.

2. Create theme

you can set some theme setting which will only affect the checkbox:

[image: checkbox theme settings]

you can use `storybook-addon-material-ui` demo [page](https://sm-react.github.io/react-theming/?theme-ind=0&theme-sidebar=true&theme-full=true&selectedKind=Material-UI&selectedStory=Components&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=sm%2Fstorybook-addon-material-ui%2Fmaterial-panel) to create your theme and download it.

Comment: Thank you @Oleg. I tried 'inputStyle','iconStyle','labelStyle' and 'style'. 'labelStyle' does change the color of label text, but none of them changes the color of checkbox. Here is the [test jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qm5r6Lfg/2/). I think a 'local' solution is what I need, because I want keep my other checkboxes using the default style.

Comment: Hey Oleg, thank you for this. I've been looking all over the internet for the properties to each element in MaterialUI to design my themes and I can't seem to find a complete doc. The material ui website doesn't have this. I've collected some for buttons and toggles, etc from different places. Is there a place I can get the full list of properties for all elements, including how to setup custom ones? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For me i just needed the table header checkbox changed, this worked for me

```
.thsvg svg{
  fill: white !important;
}


<TableHeader
   className="thsvg"
    displaySelectAll={true}
    adjustForCheckbox={true}
    enableSelectAll={true}>
  <TableRow>     
    <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
  </TableRow>
</TableHeader>
```

Answer (score 4):

the checkBox has attribute named color and it can have value of **default** or **primary** or **secondary** like :

```
 <Checkbox
   onChange={doSth}
   value="checkedIncomplete"
   color="primary"
  />
```

you can change primary and secondary colors in simple way by over writing their classes Css which for primary is : `.MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary` and for secondary is : `.MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary`

so you can edit in Css : `.MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary { color : 'yourColor'}`

Answer (score 3):

MUI 5 Theme:

```
import { checkboxClasses } from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

export const muiTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiCheckbox: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    color: 'blue',
                    [`&.${checkboxClasses.checked}`]: {
                        color: 'blue',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on material-ui 4.1.
Define `color` property on with value =`"primary"` on `Checkbox`

```
<Checkbox color="primary"...>
```

Overwrite material-ui's styling wrt the primary color. Add this entry into a css file which gets imported into the javascript code that renders the `Checkbox`.

```
.MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary.Mui-checked {
color: #e82997 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a custom Icon for both check and unchecked condition then style the icons of your checkbox
for example:
`<Checkbox checkedIcon={<CustomIcon style={{color:'red'}}/>} icon={<CustomIcon/>} inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'decorative checkbox' }} {...props} />`

Answer (score 1):

For any person coming later for an answer, 
if the `labelStyle` and `iconStyle` do not work for you 
and you want to be able to change the color later try the following thing:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, {color: string}, "root">({
    root: {
        color: (props: {color: string}) => props.color,
    },
})

export default function ColoredCheckbox() {
     const styles = useStyles({color: "#whatevercoloryouwant"})
     return <Checkbox color="default" className={styles.root} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiCheckbox: {
            defaultProps: {
                // disableRipple: true,
            }, 
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    color: 'black',
                    '&.Mui-checked': {
                        color: 'black', 
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```