# How to add custom Material UI palette colors

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-ui

I'm trying to establish my own palette colors to match my branding in Material UI. So far I can only get the primary and secondary colors to work when applied as the background color to buttons. When I add my own variable names, like use "accent" as shown as an example from Material UI's website, the button defaults to grey.

Here is my *MyTheme.js* code:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import purple from 'material-ui/colors/purple';

export default createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: { // works
          main: '#165788',
          contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        secondary: { // works
          main: '#69BE28',
          contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        companyBlue: { // doesn’t work - defaults to a grey button
            main: '#65CFE9',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        companyRed: { // doesn’t work - grey button
            main: '#E44D69',
            contrastText: '#000',
        },
        accent: { // doesnt work - grey button
            main: purple, // import purple doesn’t work
            contrastText: '#000',
        },
    },
});
```

Here is my *App.js* code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyTheme from './MyTheme';
import './App.css';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={MyTheme}>
          <Button variant="raised" >
          Default
          </Button>
          <Button variant="raised" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
          Primary
          </Button>
          <Button variant="raised" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>
          Secondary
          </Button>
          <Button variant="raised" color="companyRed" className={classes.button}>
          Company Red
          </Button>
          <Button variant="raised" color="accent" className={classes.button}>
          Accent
          </Button>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: This is a strange one. Not sure what you mean by "purple" doesn't work, but you should have e.g. `purple[500]` or something in your `MyTheme` anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Other than needing to change `purple` in your `MyTheme` to be something like `purple[500]`, I'm not sure why this wouldn't work for you. You may not be able override anything other than the `primary` and `secondary` in this way.

Regardless, here's a workaround:

In `MyTheme.js`:

```
accent: { backgroundColor: purple[500], color: '#000' }
```

Then in `App.js`:

```
<Button
  variant="raised"
  style={MyTheme.palette.accent}
  className={classes.primary}>
    Accent
</Button>
```

A working example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bd92xq).

Comment: Hey Colin, I need my own variables to work with hex colors. The purple was just a test.

Comment: Sure, but `purple` wasn't valid since it was an object.

Comment: Thanks! I checked out your example and my custom colored variable works. For anyone looking at this post, here is the answer:   <Button  style={MyTheme.palette.companyRed} >

Comment: and in your theme file change main to backgroundColor and contrastText to color.

Answer (score 58):

The Material UI palette is [extendable](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-configuration-variables), but you need to do a couple of things to create a new color and apply it to your `Button` component.

First, let’s define a theme with a custom color variable. You can use `augmentColor()` to generate the [`PaletteColor`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/f8fcae6bfc1e365aac0b82f1ae0dd2ad8438052c/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L49-L54) so it can be consumed in your `Button`:

```
import { purple } from "@mui/material/colors";

const { palette } = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    myAwesomeColor: palette.augmentColor({ color: purple }),
    // Use this code if you want to use an arbitrary color
    // myAwesomeColor: palette.augmentColor({
    //   color: {
    //     main: "#00ff00"
    //   }
    // })
  }
});
```

Then update your [TypeScript definition](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables), so it can recognize the property `myAwesomeColor` when referencing the `Palette` and `PaletteOption` objects (skip this step if you're using JavaScript). You also need to extend the `Button`'s color props definition, because by default it [only accepts](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/f8fcae6bfc1e365aac0b82f1ae0dd2ad8438052c/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.d.ts#L33) the following values:

```
'inherit' | 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'success' | 'error' | 'info' | 'warning'
```

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Palette {
    myAwesomeColor: string;
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    myAwesomeColor: string;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    myAwesomeColor: true;
  }
}
```

The final step is to inject the custom theme and set the custom color for your `Button`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Button color="myAwesomeColor" variant="contained">
    AWESOME
  </Button>
</ThemeProvider>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related answer

- [Change primary and secondary colors in Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69834616/9449426)

Comment: This worked for me when accessing the custom property inside of the callback of the `styled` function from `@mui/material/styles`. On the contrary, I get a "property doesnt exist" when accessing it through the returned value of the "useTheme" hook from `@mui/material/styles`. Any hints? :/

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69723309/9449426) answer, put the component that uses `useTheme` inside `ThemeProvider`. See my updated codesandbox for reference.

Comment: @NearHuscarl in your example (and mui's docs) you add a module augmentation specifically for buttons.  I think most folks would like to add a color to the root(?) palette and watch it augment every mui component.  Have you found a solution where you don't have to augment every component to get the color to be globally available?

Comment: @MattJones Anyone find a solution to adding a custom color to the  to the root palette?

Comment: The last step there "ButtonPropsColorOverrides", is not mentioned anywhere on the official site: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/

Took me ages to find your answer and solve my problem, so thank you very much!

Comment: I always found it so weird you need to extend both Palette and PaletteOptions :(

Comment: Using this solution, I'm getting TypeScript error: `Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2352)` when I try to reference the added palette color from the `styled()(({ theme }) => ({ ... }))` method. What type (if any) should I specify for the first curried function argument?

Comment: You sir are a god sent, I have been looking how to accomplish this for a solid two hours till I stumbled upon your answer.

Comment: I'm using create-react-app and I had to do `export interface Palette extends MuiPalette {...}` in my `mui.d.ts` in order to make the module augmentation successfully work.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a problem adding a custom palette as follows:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#2a9461"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#494c7d"
    },
    companyRed: {
       main: "#E44D69",
       contrastText: "#000",
    },
  }
});
```

Using MUI colors like "purple" has to be accessed by the object key because each color comes with shade values from 50 to 900 (light to dark):

```
import { purple } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#2a9461"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#494c7d"
    },
    companyRed: {
       main: '#E44D69',
       contrastText: "#000",
    },
    accent: {
      main: purple[50] // Or purple[100], purple[200]
    }
  }
});
```

But if you are looking to create your own purple palette (and other colors) to match the branding, you can add a new js file with all custom colors and shades and import it in the main app:

*colors.js* file

```
export const green = {
  50: "#dbece2",
  100: "#a7d0b8",
  200: "#6eb18b",
  300: "#2a9461",
  400: "#008044",
  500: "#006c27",
  600: "#006020",
  700: "#005116",
  800: "#00410b",
  900: "#002700"
};
export const purple = {
  50: "#e9eaf0",
  100: "#c7cada",
  200: "#a3a8c1",
  300: "#8186a7",
  400: "#686c95",
  500: "#505485",
  600: "#494c7d",
  700: "#414371",
  800: "#393964",
  900: "#2d2a4c"
};
```

```
import { green, purple } from "./colors";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: green[300]
    },
    secondary: {
      main: purple[600]
    },
    primaryLight: {
      main: green[50]
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a more detailed explanation of creating custom themes, palettes, and colors https://muhimasri.com/blogs/how-to-customize-theme-and-colors-in-material-ui/

Answer (score 0):

for MUI v5 this seems to work for me:

```
let theme = createTheme({
  palette: { 
    customPrimary: {
      main: '#ff3402',
    },
  },
});


theme = createTheme(theme, {
  components: {
   MuiAppBar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        colorPrimary: {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.customPrimary.main,
        },
      },
    },
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those creating a custom color in their theme in Typescript this is how I did it.
I added the yellow and dark color types:

```
  interface Palette {
    dark?: Palette['primary'];
    yellow?: Palette['primary'];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    dark?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    yellow?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}
```

Then set them based on type. This took me a second to figure out. While I added dark a type on PaletteOptions, it's type then became like the rest as PaletteColorOptions which has the following type:

```
export type PaletteColorOptions = SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial;

export interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}
```

So I used main to define the color in it's type.

```
const theme = createTheme({
dark: {
      main: '#5b504b'
    },
    yellow: {
      main: '#f4e6c2',
      dark: '#e1d7bd',
    }
}
```

Hope that helps anyone with the Typescript typing problem.