# How to change Material UI Radio button checked color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, material-ui

The `color` prop can only take three values (default, primary, secondary) but what if I want my radio to be green for example?

So I tried overriding with `classes` prop like so :

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  radio: {
    colorPrimary: {
    '&$checked': {
      color: 'blue'
    }
  },
  checked: {},
  } 
})
```

And then inside the component :

```
<FormControlLabel
   classes={{root: classes.formControlLabelRoot, label: classes.formControlLabel}}
   value="week"
   control={<Radio disableRipple classes={{colorPrimary: classes.radio}} />}
   label="Every week (Monday at 12:00)"
/>
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found a solution :

```
const styles = theme => ({
  radio: {
    '&$checked': {
      color: '#4B8DF8'
    }
  },
  checked: {}
})
```

And inside the component:

```
<FormControlLabel
  classes={{root: classes.formControlLabelRoot, label: classes.formControlLabel}}
  value="day"
  control={
    <Radio
      disableRipple
      classes={{root: classes.radio, checked: classes.checked}}
    />
  }
  label="Every Day (at 12:00)"
/>
```

You must add the `root` key.

Comment: Probably just me being silly but for anyone else who has this issue... `$checked` is a back reference to the local rule `checked: {}` defined below.  So if the `checked` key is, say `radioChecked`, then your rule above has to reflect that i.e. `&$radioChecked: ...`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `sx` prop in **MUI v5** to style the checked and uncheck states like below:

```
<Radio
  {...props}
  sx={{
    '&, &.Mui-checked': {
      color: 'magenta',
    },
  }}
/>
```

If you want to use a custom color in `color` prop, you can extend the palette in `createTheme()`:

```
const { palette } = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    pinky: palette.augmentColor({ color: pink }),
    summer: palette.augmentColor({ color: yellow }),
  },
});
```

Then use it like this in your component:

```
{/* pre-defined color */}
<Radio {...props} />
<Radio {...props} color="secondary" />
<Radio {...props} color="success" />
<Radio {...props} color="default" />
{/* custom color */}
<Radio {...props} color="pinky" />
<Radio {...props} color="summer" />
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related Answer

- [How to add custom MUI palette colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264263/9449426)

Answer (score 8):

I have a different solution, for a project-wide theme.

```
const theme = {
  overrides: {
    MuiRadio: {
      root: {
        color: 'green',
      },
      colorSecondary: {
        '&$checked': {
          color: 'green',
        },
      },
    },
  },
},

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme(theme)

<ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
  // rest of app goes here
</ThemeProvider>
```

This way, all Material-UI Radio elements in the app have a green outer circle, and are also a green circle inside when checked.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to use **colorSecondary** class key instead of colorPrimary because the radio button has color of **secondary** as default

also you can override the default values for primary and secondary and default colors using **createMuiTheme** and **MuiThemeProvider** component in your root component you can

```
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: purple[500] }, // Purple and green play nicely together.
    secondary: { main: '#11cb5f' }, // This is just green.A700 as hex.
  },
});

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <Button color="primary">Primary</Button>
        <Button color="secondary">Secondary</Button>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

as you can see in the example below you just wrap your components with **MuiThemeProvider**  and every component now will have new primary and secondary color

check this link from material-ui website for more information
[Themes](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)

Comment: Could you provide an example with the **colorSecondary** class ?

Comment: change **colorPrimary**  to **colorSecondary**

Comment: This is not working i tried using the **checked** class also

Comment: ok you can use MuiThemeProvider for now and change the default colors for primary and secondary

Answer (score 3):

In the latest MUI (v5.6.4 at the moment of writing this), you can apply style overrides on the theme level, if you want to change the colors everywhere the Radios are used in the application. For example, this is how I've overridden the styles for the Radio, and a few other components:

```
import { createTheme, checkboxClasses, radioClasses, ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material";

import { FONT_FAMILY } from "shared/src/theme/typography";
import palette from "shared/src/theme/palette";

const themeObj: Partial<ThemeOptions> = {
  typography: { fontFamily: FONT_FAMILY, fontSize: 16 },
  components: {
    MuiRadio: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: `var(--neutrals-800, ${palette.neutrals["800"]})`,
          [`&.${radioClasses.checked}`]: {
            color: `var(--secondary-500, ${palette.secondary["500"]})`,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiCheckbox: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontSize: "0.94rem",
          color: `var(--neutrals-800, ${palette.neutrals["800"]})`,
          [`&.${checkboxClasses.checked}`]: {
            color: `var(--secondary-500, ${palette.secondary["500"]})`,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiFormControlLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: `var(--text-secondary, ${palette.text.secondary})`,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

export const theme = createTheme(themeObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this with a styled component

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';

const CssRadio = withStyles({
    colorSecondary: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        '&$checked': {
            color: 'hotpink',
          },
    },
    checked: {}
})(Radio)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the color of the visible radio button and don't want to change the button color (default blue), then you can just use this.

```
control={<Radio sx={{color:'white'}}/>}
```