# How to add custom named colors to Material-UI Theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to add a named color to my theme such as `warn`

```
import React from 'react'
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: '#30b5c8', warn: { main: '#000000' } },
    secondary: { main: '#fadc35' },
    warn: { main: '#ff9100', light: '#ffa733', dark: '#b26500' },
  },
})

export default ({ children }) => {
  return <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</MuiThemeProvider>
}
```

However, the `warn` property of this object is ignored by material-ui. Is it possible to add this `color/property`?

## `Material-ui`'s `palette` once rendered

```
  {
    common: { black: '#000', white: '#fff' },
    type: 'light',
    primary: {
      light: '#7986cb',
      main: '#3f51b5',
      dark: '#303f9f',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#ff4081',
      main: '#f50057',
      dark: '#c51162',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    },
    error: {
      light: '#e57373',
      main: '#f44336',
      dark: '#d32f2f',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    },
    grey: {
      '50': '#fafafa',
      '100': '#f5f5f5',
      '200': '#eeeeee',
      '300': '#e0e0e0',
      '400': '#bdbdbd',
      '500': '#9e9e9e',
      '600': '#757575',
      '700': '#616161',
      '800': '#424242',
      '900': '#212121',
      A100: '#d5d5d5',
      A200: '#aaaaaa',
      A400: '#303030',
      A700: '#616161'
    },
    contrastThreshold: 3,
    getContrastText: [Function: getContrastText],
    augmentColor: [Function: augmentColor],
    tonalOffset: 0.2,
    text: {
      primary: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
      secondary: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)',
      disabled: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)',
      hint: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'
    },
    divider: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
    background: { paper: '#fff', default: '#fafafa' },
    action: {
      active: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)',
      hover: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)',
      hoverOpacity: 0.08,
      selected: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14)',
      disabled: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)',
      disabledBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)'
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest to look  at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069724/how-to-add-multiple-material-ui-palette-colors)

Comment: I do not see the same theme result as what you are showing (https://codesandbox.io/s/theme-palette-pm4hb). The palette you're showing doesn't even include your customizations to `primary` and `secondary`. You seem to be looking at the default theme rather than the theme created by your code.

Comment: Ah yes indeed Ryan. Very good point. I had not realised this.

Answer (score 1):

You need the function *createPalette*, you can see [the  definition here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/27fe6a30e5e5432036e8a0ce8a409b75dfb7f2dc/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js). Sadly that function is not exposed, so, you had two ways to do what you want:

1. Get out that function and use it.
2. Make it the variants of colors with [this website](http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%233f51b5) and with that result choose wisely every lighten and generate contrastText with the function *getContrastRatio* located in *'@material-ui/core/styles'*.