# How can I change the focused color of a TextField?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am making use of Material-UI React library and I need to change the border color of a `TextField` when it is clicked or focused as the case maybe.

Here is what I have tried:

```
const useFormFieldStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  input: {
    borderWidth: '1px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input:focused': {
      borderColor: 'green',
    }
  }
}));
```

Yet, the `borderColor` is still blue despite all my efforts.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 16):

#### Material-UI v5

The easiest way to change the focus color of the `TextField` is to set the [`color`](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#color) props which is quite limited because it only accepts these values, (the color can be [extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264263/9449426) but you need to write a bit of code).

```js
'primary' | 'secondary' | 'error' | 'info' | 'success' | 'warning'
```

If you want to change to an arbitrary color, use the following code:

```
const CssTextField = styled(TextField, {
  shouldForwardProp: (props) => props !== "focusColor"
})((p) => ({
  // input label when focused
  "& label.Mui-focused": {
    color: p.focusColor
  },
  // focused color for input with variant='standard'
  "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
    borderBottomColor: p.focusColor
  },
  // focused color for input with variant='filled'
  "& .MuiFilledInput-underline:after": {
    borderBottomColor: p.focusColor
  },
  // focused color for input with variant='outlined'
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderColor: p.focusColor
    }
  }
}));
```

##### Usage

```html
<CssTextField focusColor='red' />
```

#### Live Demo

[image: Edit ColorTextFields Material Demo (forked)]

#### Material-UI v4

See [Customized inputs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs) section. The example below styles the focused color border and label of the `TextField` in 3 variants:

```
const focusedColor = "orange";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    // input label when focused
    "& label.Mui-focused": {
      color: focusedColor
    },
    // focused color for input with variant='standard'
    "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
      borderBottomColor: focusedColor
    },
    // focused color for input with variant='filled'
    "& .MuiFilledInput-underline:after": {
      borderBottomColor: focusedColor
    },
    // focused color for input with variant='outlined'
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
        borderColor: focusedColor
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```
export default function CustomizedInputs() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", columnGap: 15 }}>
      <TextField className={classes.root} variant="outlined" />
      <TextField className={classes.root} variant="standard" />
      <TextField className={classes.root} variant="filled" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67139471/how-to-change-the-focused-color-of-a-react-material-ui-textfield]

Answer (score 10):

Now using the sx props from the Mui Textfield you can also use the following to change the color of the outline on focus:

```
const style = {
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderColor: "green"
    }
  }
}    

<TextField sx={style} ...(your other props)/>
```

If you want to also change the color of the label when the field is focused, you can addthis to the style variable:

```
const style = {
  "& label.Mui-focused": {
    color: "green"
  },
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderColor: "green"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great with MUI v5. Tested with Outlined TextField type with label. Thanks!